# Are OpenGLES2.0 android devices guaranteed to support stencil buffer?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Are OpenGLES2.0 android devices guaranteed to support at least some number (>0) of stencil buffer bits?

I'm seeing mixed messages. Stencil testing is mentioned in the specification, and the various stencil functions are listed in the man pages, so I thought this would imply it is part of the core api.

I also see that several stencil formats `GL_OES_STENCIL[148]` are listed as extensions, so I'm not sure if this means that phones which claim 'support' for OpenGLES2.0 are required to support stencil buffers, or if they are optional extensions?

I've also read in a few places that some android phones do not support the stencil buffer, though I didn't see what version of OpenGLES they were referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_cm_spec_2.0.24.pdf):

> **4.1 Per-Fragment Operations**
>
> All OpenGL 2.0 per-fragment operations are supported, except for occlusion queries, logic-ops, alpha test and color index related operations. Depth and stencil operations are supported, but a selected config is not required to include a depth or stencil buffer with the caveat that an OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation must support at least one config with a depth bit depth of 16 or higher and a stencil bit depth of 8 or higher.

Does this answer your question?